# Is it possible to remove a nested view in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, view, zend-framework2

I have some nested views inherited from the parent of a class and would like to remove a single child out of it...
As example, parent code:

```
    Class Father
    {
        public function IndexAction()
        {
            ...
            $view = new ViewModel();
            $view->addChild($viewToNest);

            return $view;
        }
    }
```

And extended example:

```
    Class Son extends Father
    {
        //This is supposed to override
        public function IndexAction()
        {
            $view = parent::IndexAction();

            #Is there anything like this?
            $view->removeChild();
            return $view;
        }
    }
```

Anybody knows a way?

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: Sorry, just added now =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation, it is specified that you can use `$view->clearChildren()` to clear out all children.

According to the documentation again, it seems that there is nothing to remove a specific child.
You must do it by yourself.

Comment: I found this clearChildren() but I was indeed hoping to find something to remove a specific one, didn't see where it said it couldn't. =/

Well, thank you anyway.

Comment: I agree, there may be some osbcure function doing that. You should check in the source code how they made clearChildren() and adapt it to make your own. :)